# Causing Bootstrap div to overflow to right instead of wrapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML that is part of a blade template:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="row">
        @foreach($images as $i)
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="{{ $i->url }}" alt="thumbnail" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" />
            </div>
        @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When too many thumbnails show up, I want them to auto overflow to the right with a scrollbar. Right now they are wrapping around to the next line.

How would I set this using CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Bootstrap by default wraps columns exceeding 12 in a row. You could modify the outer `div` like so:

```
<div class="row customClass">
    @foreach($images as $i)
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img src="{{ $i->url }}" alt="thumbnail" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" />
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

And the correspondinig `CSS` would look something like:

```
 div.row.customClass {
   overflow-x: auto;
   white-space: nowrap;
 }

div.row.customClass [class*="col-md"] {
   display: inline-block;
   float: none; /* Very important */
}
```

Hope, this gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this... change the third line to read something like:

```
<div class="row scroll-horizontal">
```

Then in your CSS

```
.scroll-horizontal {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```